# mallet error IllegalArgumentExce ption: Couldn't read InstanceList from file complaints.mallet

Tags: java, mallet

I am trying to use Mallet for a research project and I keep getting the same error.
Here are the instructions I have been using:

Once you have all of the files in the Complaints folder

**Step 1:** Clean the files using CAT Scanner

- Open the program from the desktop
- Click on “Remove Special Characters from Text Files”
- Click File, Clean Individual Files
- Select all of the files in the Complaints folder
- Click Open
- Click Clean
- Go to the Complaints folder in the C: drive and remove the Backup folder so that only the cleaned files are in the Complaints folder

**Step 2** – create the .mallet file

- Open the command prompt (search for it in the Start menu)
- Type cd .. (cd space period period)
- Type cd .. again (you should just have C:\> on the last line)
- Type cd mallet
- Copy and paste the syntax from the “Data Import Routine” file…there’s nothing you need to change bin\mallet import-dir -- input C:\mallet\complaints -- output C:\mallet\complaint.mallet -- keep-sequence -- remove-stopwords

**Step 3** – running the topic modeling

- In the command prompt, copy and paste the syntax from the “Topic Model Routine” text file.
- Highlighted below is what you need to change (basically you are just telling it how many topics to generate – 3, 5, 10, 15, 25, 50) bin\mallet train-topics -- input complaint.mallet -- num-topics 3 -- optimize-interval 3 -- output-state topic-state.gz -- output-topic- keys complaint_3_keys.txt -- output-doc- topics complaint_3_composition.txt
- For every time you run an analysis you will get 2 files of output (found in the mallet folder, labeled compliant_x_keys.txt and complaint_x_composition).txt). Open these and copy and paste into Excel.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the -s bug: the commands are creating the file `complaint.mallet` and then trying to read `complaints.mallet`.